# A surjective morphism of complex algebraic varieties with smooth fibers that is a submersion

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a surjective morphism of irreducible complex algebraic varieties with nonsingular fibers. Moreover, assume that each *geometric* fiber $f^{-1}(y)$ is isomorphic to an affine space ${\Bbb A}^{n(y)}$.

> **Question 1.** What are  algebraic-geometrical conditions on $f$ that imply that $f$ is a ***submersion***, that is, the induced maps on the tangent spaces are surjective?

> **Question 2.** The same question in the case when $y\to n(y)$  is a ***constant*** function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct notion of a submersion in algebraic geometry is a smooth morphism. The key statement for your situation is that a flat morphism locally of finite presentation with smooth fibers is smooth (ref [Stacks 01V8](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V8)). Assuming "variety" means at least a scheme of finite type over a field, your map is locally of finite presentation ([01T8](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01T8) + [01TX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01TX)) and it has smooth fibers by assumption. Thus all we need to do to guarantee smoothness is to show that your morphism is flat.

In your second case, if you know that $X$ is Cohen-Macaulay and $Y$ is regular, this follows from *Miracle Flatness* (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/662890) of Emerton). Without this assumption in the second case, or in the first case, I am struggling to think of big general results that will be useful to you. Perhaps perusing [some](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00MD) [criteria](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/051E) [for flatness](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00R3) will be helpful to you.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer! Yes, by a complex algebraic variety I mean a separated integral scheme of finite type over the field $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that a smooth morphism of algebraic varieties over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ is automatically surjective on tangent spaces of closed points?

Comment: I have edited my question: the word "geometric" is added. Do I understand correctly that your answer is still valid for the edited question?

Comment: Yes to both. See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/375415) for smooth implies submersion (with no assumptions on the characteristic). For the addition of the word geometric, just note that if the fiber over $y$ is $\Bbb A^{n(y)}_{k(y)}$, then the geometric fiber is just $\Bbb A^{n(y)}_{\overline{k(y)}}$.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!

Comment: Now I would like to have a *reference* for the following statement: Let $$\varphi\colon X\to Y$$ be a surjective morphism of  *smooth* $\Bbb C$-varieties. Then $\varphi$ is smooth if and only if the map on $\Bbb C$-points is a submersion. I can refer to the proof [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/375415). However, I would prefer to refer to a book, or a published paper, or the Stacks Project, or an arXiv preprint.